# Basic Animation for Android devices

Tags: android, flash

There is an instructional cooking app (for Android devices only) that I want to make. Alongside the recipe, I want to put a really simple video in the bottom - showing contents coming together in the right order. I'm using simple sprites.

What can I use to animate those sprites? By experience, I have only used Flash for something like this. Publishing as swf is, however, risky. Publishing as animated gif is another option, but then I will be using the same platform again.
Is there any other format to publish in? Is there any other IDE I could make these animations in?

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'Canvas' drawing in android.  Then use a Sprite sheet to create animation(This is basically like stop motion photography).

Answer (score 0):

In case you want simple object animation(translating them and merging in right order).
You can animate x or y property so that item translate, more on [Property Animation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html#object-animator)

Here is a sample to translate foo along x-axis from 0 to 1 in 1000 ms :

```
ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(foo, "x", 0f, 1f);
anim.setDuration(1000);
anim.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could do animations like this:

Create an XML file in res/anim/pull_in_from_right.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:duration="500"
       android:fromXDelta="100%"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:toXDelta="0%" />
```

Then in your java code:

```
circle = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.circle_pic);
perform_circleMove = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.pull_in_from_right);
circle.startAnimation(perform_circleMove);
```

The above code moves a circle from XDelta of 200% to 0% - it comes in from the right side of the screen.